# Как вычислить пересечение временных интервалов?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, momentjs

Есть moment.js, есть парные инпуты для ввода времени (start и end), время в формате "HH-mm". Таких полей несколько. Как можно вычислить, не пересекаются ли они?

Comment: Аналогичные вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768164 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/734286

Comment: @Kromster там php и java, так и не уловил смысл. Мне для JS бы ..

Comment: Принцип тот же, это же все классические языки программирования, а вам нужен лишь алгоритм.

Comment: в документации есть функция [isBetween](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) я думаю она вам поможет. Надо перебрать все `start` и `end` не находятся ли они в интервале друг у друга.

Comment: можно воспользоваться [moment-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-range/v/1.0.2)

Comment: Спасибо, `isBetween` то что нужно!

Comment: @Vladimir оформите Ваш комментарий как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B документации `moment.js`есть функция [isBetween](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) я думаю она вам поможет. Надо перебрать все `start` и `end` не находятся ли они в интервале друг у друга